# White screen while opening visual studio

Tags: visual-studio-2015, devenv

I installed visual studio 14.0 yesterday  and there were some problem before installation itself although I installed it and when I opened it it showed a dll file missing so I downloaded it and after that it showed component missing so I went to devenev(I don't know what is it I did it according to an early question on stack overflow )and I make it run as administrator and it came but it isn't working.

It showed a white colour.please help.
I am using Windows 7 32 bit

Comment: Sorry I can't post picture

Comment: This is a question for Super User, not Stack Overflow.

Comment: I am not posting these questions for reputation

Comment: That has nothing to do with this. The question is just on the wrong site.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Try from your white screen:
Press: <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> for *Tools*, then <kbd>O</kbd> for *Options* and untick the following boxes as shown, click *OK* and reopen Visual Studio.

[image: Solution]

Hope it helps.

Comment: I started to have this problem when I remotely connected to my computer and this answer solved the issue. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Thank you! I was getting a white screen filling the IDE window when remoting, but the rest of the desktop renders fine. This has so far fixed the issue. Many thanks!

Comment: In case if Visual Experience menu is also not visible, then from General tab press following keys: 3x`Tab`, 1x`A`, 1x`Tab`, 1x`E`, 1x`Tab`, 1x`U` and `Enter`.

Comment: @sh_ark WOW man, you saved me!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: For vs 2022, you could press: 6x `Tab`, 1x `a`, 1x `Tab`, 1x `u`, 1x `e` after click General option. Then press `Enter`.

Answer (score 5):

I had a similar issue today.
When opening up VS 2017, i was presented with the normal black VS 2017 splash screen and after that closed, it opened a blank white screen.

After trying Tim and portogas's methods from the other answers posted, i still had the problem.
I spoke with Microsoft who said i had a corrupt install, so went through the pain of uninstalling and re-installing VS2017 to find out i still had the same issue!

I also noticed i had developed this problem for VS2015 also which i thought was strange.

After opening VS2017 one more time and moving my mouse over the blank screen, i noticed that i could see the mouse cursor change at certain points and when hovering over the top right corner, a popover would appear saying "Close".

I opened device manager and noticed that my NVIDIA driver had an issue, so i reinstalled the drivers and updated the Intel HD Graphics 530 graphics driver whilst i was at it.

Same issue with white screen.
I then disabled the Intel driver, and opened VS again, and it worked!

After some more playing about, i re-enabled the Intel driver and opened the NVIDIA control panel, changed the 3D settings from Auto-Select to the High-performance NVIDIA processor and all now appears to be working well!

Comment: Much appreciated! An app I had created in Visual Studio starting doing the "white screen thing", and I couldn't figure out what the problem was. I thought, "No problem! I'll just fire up VS and run it through the debugger and see what I see!" Lo and behold, VS had the same issue. Changing both programs to prefer the NVidia card fixed the issue.

Answer (score 2):

It seems like you have a corrupt installation and it would be advisable to [repair the installation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa983433(v=vs.90).aspx)

> 1) Click Start, click Control Panel, and then click Programs.
>   2) Click Programs and Features and then select the Visual Studio Edition you installed.
>   3) Click Uninstall/Change.
>   4) In the setup wizard, select Repair or Reinstall and then click Next.
>   5) Follow the remaining instructions in the installation wizard to finish.

If that doesn't work you should complete a full uninstall.

If the uninstall doesn't work please try the [fixit link](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/mats/program_install_and_uninstall/en) from microsoft.com

If the fixit link from Microsoft doesnt work you can use the [manual uninstall instructions found on msdn](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/heaths/2015/07/17/removing-visual-studio-components-left-behind-after-an-uninstall/).

Also make sure your system meets the [minimum system requirements](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/downloads/visual-studio-2015-system-requirements-vs.aspx#1) and you should review the [compatibility](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/products/visual-studio-2015-compatibility-vs.aspx) page:

Comment: Did the repair fix it?

Comment: The repairing is going on my net is slow

Comment: Nope,it didn't worked the repair stops at a certain area and I make it stay like that for a day then also it didn't worked why?

Comment: Tim penner,please reply.

Comment: I think its obvious you have a bad installation.  If repair didn't work how about a full uninstall followed by a reinstall

Comment: Uninstallation too isn't working,the progressing of the applying stops at a certain stage,why

Comment: Can I delete the files?

Comment: Tim,are you receiving

Comment: Try this link from microsoft to attempt to fix the app that cannot be uninstalled: https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/mats/program_install_and_uninstall/en

Comment: also make sure that your system meets the requirements: https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/downloads/visual-studio-2015-system-requirements-vs.aspx#1

Comment: and here are the instructions for manual removal https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/heaths/2015/07/17/removing-visual-studio-components-left-behind-after-an-uninstall/

Comment: I am using a thoshiba net book is that bcz of it?

Comment: very possible; what are the specs and CPU model/generation

Comment: Repairing Visual Studio 2015 Community version solved my issue

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. I solved this one by doing the following:

1. Run visual studio from command prompt
   devenv.exe /resetsettings
2. Open Tools -> Import and Export Settings
3. Select "Reset all settings"

After resetting all settings I could open Visual Studio 2017 normally again.

But after that you need to login to get the full license instead of the trial one.

Answer (score 0):

It worked for me:

1. Right click on pinned(pin to start menu if not) visual studio icon
2. Click Visual studio insiders

Answer (score -1):

Well first press key windows + letter r , then write : devenv.exe /resetsettings and press ok